# Not showing "Amendments" or "request" button to accept the updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to create new app. But iTunes connect top it shows me message below:

Agreements, Tax, and Banking

The updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement needs to be reviewed.
In order to update your existing apps and submit new apps to the App Store, the user with the Legal role (Team Agent) must review and accept the updated agreement in their account on the developer website.

I have searched in stack overflow and found some solution, but not able to find the button to accept the updated Apple developer program license.

i have not found iTunesconnect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking -> request button in Agreements, Tax, and Banking and also not found any iTunesconnect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking -> Amendments.

The message is look like below:
[image]

In Agreements, Tax, and Banking shows me below:
[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as the user with the Legal role?

Comment: @HAS Yes, There is only one user through which i login in.

Comment: What happens when you press that blue link in the text?

Comment: @HAS When i click on "account on the developer website". It will nevigate to me https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/58YU44W43Z and it shows me create certificate&ids&profiles page.

Comment: In that case I'd advise you to contact dev support. It might well be that the new website is still broke.

Comment: @HAS How can i contact to developer support ? Thanks for help me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/ You're welcome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109300/discussion-between-jignesh-kanani-and-has).

Comment: @JigneshKanani Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @MattMc Yes, it resolved. try to accept the agreements. which may be pending to accept in another section and and wait for 2-4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/$AppleTeamID as the Account Owner and accept the agreement from there.

I'll concede this was not obvious. A similar prompt should exist in Agreements, Tax and Banking or a URL in the warning!

Be sure to replace $AppleTeamID with your Team ID associated with your Apple Dev account.

Comment: yes! I found essentially the same advice here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133703 and it finally saved the day

Answer (score 0):

After clicked on done it will navigate to your  developer account and where you have to  **tap** on **membership** and accept the all information.After accepting refresh your itunes connect page you see that warning is removed

Comment: There is no accept button or anything under membership. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Visit [tv.apple.com](https://tv.apple.com/), Sign in,

After signing in, the license agreement should pop up, accept it and you're good to go.