# The updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement needs to be reviewed. Can't find any agreement to accept

Tags: ios

[image]

I am trying to upload my app from itunes connect and I am getting prompt that I need to review new apple developer program licence agreement. But I can't find any agreement to accept. Please help.

Comment: Presumably, someone else has the “Legal role” in App Store Connect. Just because you have permissions to distribute/manage the app doesn’t mean you’re the one with permission to authorize the updated license agreement (i.e., those who are authorized to enter legal agreements on behalf of the company). Often this is whomever originally set up the account and provided documentation about the legal status of the business entity. That’s who needs to sign in and accept this updated license.

Comment: We only have one user under Users&Roles. And I am using the same email that was used to create the account. This user has Admin,AccountHolder roles.

Comment: @SyedAliRaza did you ever figure this out? I am staring at the same screen and I feel very dazed and confused that I also cannot tell what step I must take to dismiss that task of reviewing a new agreement.

Comment: similiar question (with more discussion) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36660280/10278

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133703 finally provided the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to insufficient permissions. So if anyone faces this kind of issue. Please make sure you have the necessary permissions.

Answer (score -2):

Okay. I have an advise for you Because today I encountered this erros. And than I tried and tried. I know it is not working without someone. I mean If you do not have any ownership on your apple account, You cannot update it. And ask owner of account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).